# OpenGL data transfer to graphics card

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, shader

Why do you need buffers in OpenGL, when you can just transfer all the data to the graphics card via uniform. As an example:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec2 pos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

why would you need the above code, when you can just have the following:

```
#version 330

uniform vec2 pos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

i really cant see the use of vao, vbo, ebo, etc.

Comment: Because a model usually has more than a single vertex? Even the simplest primitive has three, which means you'd need to have at least three uniforms. Are you really going to set all uniforms and render a single triangle, thousands of times, for a more complex scene?

Comment: Attributes are per vertex (this is what you call buffers). Uniforms are per draw call (so, per bunch of vertices).

Comment: "you can just transfer all the data to the graphics card via uniform"  Citation needed.

Answer (score 3):

Let's forget for the moment the fact that uniforms are *uniform*: their values do not change within a drawing call (and therefore what you're asking for is not possible).

Uniform variables of this sort are set by calling `glUniform` of some form. So to make this "work", you must call `glUniform` once for every vertex you want to render in your entire scene. A number that may well number in the *millions* for the entire scene. So every frame of rendering, you need to call `glUniform` millions of times.

Plus, that only provides a single value, in this case a position. If a vertex has a normal, color, texture coordinate, or any combination of the above (or other things), then you need to make a `glUniform` call for each of those values.

If you have a 100 million vertices in a scene, and each vertex has 6 attributes, that's 600 million calls of that one function. *Every frame*. This is not a recipe for performance.

It would be far faster if the GPU could just look at its own storage for the data, wouldn't it? Rather than having the CPU shepherd every quantum of data individually? This would be especially true if you want to render the same model in multiple places. With your way, each time you draw that model, you have to make all the `glUniform` calls again. If the GPU just has the data, you can say "render that model over here, with these parameters".

Comment: Though I agree with the rest of your answer, I disagree with the first sentence. Why can't you use a uniform array of values (with ``gl_VertexID`` to get the index)?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget: That is not a scalable solution, as uniform arrays are *extremely* limited in storage.